# Passing argument to inner function Matlab

Tags: matlab

So I'm trying to write a function for a triple integral which depends ultimately on variable q which is a final limit of integration, and also a variable b which helps parameterize the function. However, this code isn't working and I'm not entirely sure what to do. I think it probably involves doing something to pass down the value of b to the nested functions, but I'm pretty new at matlab, any help is appreciated.

```
function [r] = test1(q,u)
b = u;
r = quad(@(k)Inner(k),-0.5.*(1-b)-b-1,q);

function [w] = Inner(k)
w = zeros(1);
for i = 1 : length(k);
    w(i) = quad(@(n)InnerIntegral(n,b).*unifpdf(k(i)-n,-1,1),0,k(i)-1,k(i)+1);
end;



function [y] = InnerIntegral(n)
y = zeros(1);
for i = 1 : length(n);
    y(i) = quad(@(m)unifpdf(n(i)-m, -b, b).*unifpdf(m,-0.5.*b,0.5.*b), n(i)-b,n(i)+b);
end;
end
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the little orange tick marks on the right side of the editor. In my copy, hovering over one says "Outer loop index 'i' is set inside a child function."

I don't know what the inputs or expected outputs of this function should be, but you should try to avoid confusing MATLAB. It has weird scoping rules. Use a different variable in the second nested function, perhaps `j` instead of `i`.